# Create a sorted linked list from an unsorted array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, linked-list

I wanted to create a sorted linked list from an unsorted array, but my implementation doesn't work 
properly for example if I inserted :

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

The output is:

```
3 3 3 4 5 6
```

Here's the code:

```
list* insert(list* head,int* arr,int size)
{
    int *index;
    index=(int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(k=j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if(index[k]==-1) {k++;j++;}
            if(arr[k]<=arr[j] && index[j]!=-1)
                k=j;
        }
        index[k]=-1;
        list* node=(list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
                node->data=arr[k];
                node->next=head;
                head=node;
    }
        return head;
}
```

Can I get some help to improve my algorithm? 
if you have a better aproach please share it.
thanks in advance!

Comment: @LEARNER What is this code doing?!

Comment: You can look up "insertion sort" for some ideas.

Comment: I was just about to submit an answer when this question was closed!  I believe the bug in your algorithm is this block: `{ k++; j++; }`  -- it's possible for `j` to go out of bounds.  It really should continue back to the top of the loop to increment `j` and check bounds: `{ k++; continue; }`

Comment: I don't believe the "similar question" qualifies as it only inserts one item into a linked list wereas this program converts an array into a linked list.  The other question is linked-list-centric, this one is array-centric and worthwhile.